# uplodify not working properly

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am trying uploadify but in vain . Upload process do not works ; i have created target folder named uploads and have proper permissions (0755 ). here is my html code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Uploadify Implementation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'

        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my uplodify.php file:

```
<?php
$targetFolder = 'photogallery/uploads/' ; 

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `755` as permission only works if the owner of the folder is the webserver user (usually `www-data`)

Comment: are you sure the owner of directory is the same as the owner of httpd process?

Comment: yes . now i have 777 permission for the same folder . but the problem still exists

Comment: the current status of the page is : i can see a button named "select a file" and can select files after that they shows a message like this: banner.jpg (277KB) - Complete. but there no file in uploads folder what will be the reason

Comment: Here is the plug in site : www.uploadify.com

Comment: seems like it can't find your target folder. Are you sure it exists?Did you try other ways of specifying your upload directory? Like for example: /name_of_project/uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Uploadify jQuery to be like this:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
    'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
       alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
    },
    'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
       alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
    }  
});
```

This will show either the error you are getting or show you where the file was successfully saved to.

Comment: i try the same but it seems wrong now the select button gone and shows a default file upload button.

Comment: Adding success and error handlers should have no effect on your buttons. Are you sure you didn't change anything else?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php'
            'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
       alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
    }  
            
        });
    });
    </script> i just try this i think there is s syntax error same problem that select button gone away..

Comment: Get FireBug for FireFox or use the developer tools in Chrome to see if you have any errors.

Comment: cillosis iam sorry it's works perfectly it's show me the error.i can resolve the problem by editing the target file as follows $targetFolder = '/workbench/photogallery/uploads'. Thank you very much.

Comment: @cillosis Thanks for sharing this snippet of code. It really helps with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`$fileParts['extension']` will return a string,  the function `in_array($needle, array $haystack)` Since the needle will be a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner. 
So try to have a look on that. The case of extension of the image you are uploading and the ones you have listed

Answer (score 0):

As a PHP newbie, I struggled with this issue for a few hours and thought I'd share what I discovered.

Like the OP, I was seeing the file(s) upload but it / they didn't appear in the `uploads` folder (despite the right permissions). Just to make things perfectly clear, this is the `index.php` that I used to help me identify my problem

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>UploadiFY Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Uploadify Demo</h1>
<form>
<div id="queue"></div>
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
            // Snippet of code shared by cillosis
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                                    alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
                                },
            'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                                    alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
                                }  
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I copied and pasted the incredibly useful snippet of code `cillosis` shared. Also, this is the version of `uploadify.php` that I employed

```
 <?php
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/

// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    // The following line 
    // $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    // didn't work in my case since I had 'index.php
    // (and all the other Uploadify files) at
    // home/mySite/public_html/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3
    // and $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was returning
    // home/mySite/public_html/Folder1
    // and so $targetPath was actually
    // home/mySite/public_html/Folder1/uploads
    // which didn't (obviously exist)

    // I ended up just using the 'getcwd' function and
    // appending $targetFolder like so
    $targetPath = getcwd() .  $targetFolder;

    // I guess another solution would be to use
    // $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and append Folder2 and Folder3
    // with the necessary slashes

    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('docx','doc','rtf'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

As is written in the comments in source code, I had issues with (understanding and) using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - so, I used `getcwd()` instead. I could arrive at this solution by using statements like

```
echo $getcwd();
```

and

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

to see what was going on. The `echos` were conveniently spat out by the code `cillosis` provided - all in a neat dialog box. Indeed, even debugging the issue was possible because of this. I realized that the files were trying to be uploaded to the wrong place because of the error that was thrown and then made readable in the dialog box.